# Finding an expression for $\tan (a+ b + y)$ which involves only $\tan a, \tan b,$ and $\tan y$.

Tags: trigonometry

How to find this ?

I'm stuck at $1$ and how to $1$ to change the tangent associated with a,b or c.

I meant this ,everybody.

$\frac{tan(a)+tan(b)+tan(y)−tan(a)tan(b)tan(y)}{1−tan(a)tan(b)−tan(a)tan(y)−tan(b)tan(y)}$

Comment: You will find this in any decent treatment of trigonometry. Did you do anything at all?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to show us how you started and where you are stuck. You might begin with the identity for $\tan{A+B)$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Are you familiar with [Trigonometric Addition Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html)?

Comment: ohh thz for reply every body

Comment: Do you mean this here $${\frac {\tan \left( a \right) +\tan \left( b \right) +\tan \left( y
 \right) -\tan \left( a \right) \tan \left( b \right) \tan \left( y
 \right) }{1-\tan \left( a \right) \tan \left( b \right) -\tan \left( 
a \right) \tan \left( y \right) -\tan \left( b \right) \tan \left( y
 \right) }}
$$

Comment: yes . i want to replace 1 with tan only

Answer (score 1):

Let's call $X=\tan(x)$ you have the addition formula $\tan(u+v)=\dfrac{U+V}{1-UV}$

- call $c=a+b$ and develop $\tan(c+y)$
- replace $C$ by $\tan(a+b)$ developpement
- simplify $\dfrac{\frac{A+B}{1-AB}+Y}{1-\frac{A+B}{1-AB}Y}$

Comment: And with one more step $\frac{A+B+Y-ABY}{1-(AB+AY+BY)}.$

Answer (score 0):

I found the appropriate answer.
I thought this is misunderstanding of english context and i don't know why?
The question from GelfAndSaul Trigonometry Book is

Represent tan(a+b+c) to only representing tan(a),tan(b) and tan(c).

I have an answer but i thought that is wrong.

So this questions means only is we can neglect to 1?